# 404 error when posting new forum post in Desire2Learn 10.0

Tags: desire2learn

I'm working with the D2L API,and am having difficulty with some POST requests.

Doing a version check (POST) using the JSON object:

```
[{ "ProductCode": "lp", "Version": "1.0" }]
```

returns correctly, providing me a valid JSON object in response, that being said I'm confident that my code to issue the call is working correctly.

When I issue a POST to create a post in a forum, however, I get a 404 in response. The JSON object I'm sending for this call is:

```
[
 {
 "ParentPostId": null,
 "Subject": "API Posted",
 "Message": {
   "Text": "This message has been posted by the API",
   "HTML": "This message has been posted by the API"
   },
 "IsAnonymous": false
 }
]
```

And the URL submitted to is `/d2l/api/le/{ver}/{orgId}/discussions/forums/{forumId}/topics/{topicId}/posts/`

I've verified that ver/orgId/forumId/topicId are all valid using a GET of a post in the same forum and topic. I've also tried quoting the values for ParentPostId and IsAnonymous both separately and in unison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the square brackets from the JSON.

An example of a successful request and response follows:

```
REQUEST  

POST https://valence.desire2learn.com/d2l/api/le/1.0/7664/discussions/forums/203/topics/508/posts/?x_b=TwULqrltMXvTE8utuLCN5O&x_a=L2Hd9WvDTcyiyu5n2AEgpg&x_d=nF61tBeuzd0EPTW7nm8iGc4MB7NeJZaNM2VlzHp0bwU&x_c=I3i_k2aANTIf2X6aFsiOdvlElSR_avvOYnA2ibcWabA&x_t=1343335429 HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

 { "ParentPostId": null, "Subject": "API Posted", "Message": { "Content": "This message has been posted by the API", "Type": "HTML" }, "IsAnonymous": false } 


RESPONSE

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 369
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Date: Thu, 26 Jul 2012 20:43:58 GMT

{"ForumId":203,"PostId":574,"TopicId":508,"PostingUserId":3667,"ThreadId":205,"ParentPostId":null,"Message":{"Text":"","Html":"This message has been posted by the API"},"Subject":"API Posted","DatePosted":"2012-07-26T20:43:58.920Z","IsAnonymous":false,"RequiresApproval":false,"IsDeleted":false,"LastEditDate":null,"LastEditedBy":null,"CanRate":false,"ReplyPostIds":[]}
```

Comment: That fixed it.. I had previously tried adding them as a fix. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the documentation for that route at http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/discuss.html#post--d2l-api-le-(D2LVERSION-version)-(D2LID-orgUnitId)-discussions-forums-(D2LID-forumId)-topics-(D2LID-topicId)-posts-, it looks like the required data structure uses a `RichTextInput` not a `RichText` for `Message`.

Try changing your `Message` field to:

```
{
   "Content": "This message has been posted by the API",
   "Type": "Text"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; You're correct that it is looking for a RichTextInput. I've tried this, and the result is the same error. I tried both type 'Text' and 'HTML'.

New JSON is:

 [ { "ParentPostId": null, "Subject": "API Posted", "Message": { "Content": "This message has been posted by the API", "Type": "HTML" }, "IsAnonymous": false } ]